# Can't upload file & validation message not appear

Tags: jsf, file-upload, jsf-2.2

i'm new in java & jsf framework. I have a situation and make me realy confused. I'm trying to create upload form in jsf, the backing bean is request scoped, user must login for using this form.  when I test to submit form, the validation message its not appear, the form just refresh without any validation/required message. I try to find the answer in google or stackoverflow but it not works. However i can upload my files when i try create simple application like my form below, without login function.

My form is look like this:

```
<h:form id="frMember" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<h:inputText id="username" value="#{memberForm.email}" required="true" requiredMessage="username_required_message" pt:placeholder="username"/><br/><br/>
<h:inputFile value="#{memberForm.fileFoto}" required="true" requiredMessage="file_required_message"/><br/>
<h:commandButton value="upload" action="#{memberForm.upload()}" class="btn btn-danger"/>
</h:form>
```

I'm using glassfish 4, JSF 2.2.7, Netbeans 8 and i'm not used 3rd party like tomahawk fileupload. I also have try googling and searching through stackoverflow for solving my problem, but still i can't solved it.

*updated*

this is my controller

```
public class MemberFormView implements Serializable {        
    private Part fileFoto;

    /**
    * Creates a new instance of MemberFormView
    */
    public MemberFormView() {
    }

    public void upload() throws IOException {
        String fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(fileFoto.getName());
        String contentType = fileFoto.getContentType();
        try (InputStream input = fileFoto.getInputStream()) {
            Files.copy(input, new File("/var/AppFile/tmp/", fileFoto.getName()).toPath());
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.2"
              xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>memberForm</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>controller.member.MemberFormView</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
</faces-config>
```

Comment: show your controller source code what annotated by `@ManagedBean`

Comment: @dovy i have update my post

Comment: try something like this: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/basic.xhtml

Comment: ok i will try... but why using primefaces if jsf already have <h:inputFile/> ?

Comment: Please don't use [java] tag when asking questions about [jsf] or any other Java EE related API. You will otherwise get knee-jerk comments/answers from users knowing nothing about JSF, which would only further confuse you. Use [java] tag only if a problem is demonstratable using a Java application class with a `main()` method and/or the technical question is about the JLS. In such case, the relevance of Java EE related tags such as [jsf] must be reconsidered (usually, they should be dropped in such case).

Comment: sorry about that, thanks for changing the tag

Comment: As to your concrete problem, are you indeed  saying that the file upload works fine when you don't require a login?

Comment: yes, i try to create simple project without login and it works fine. but when i try to implement in my real code, it doesn't work. the form just refresh without validation message appearing.

Comment: If the login is causing all the trouble, why are you in your question focusing only on the upload form being the cause, not on the login being the cause? Or are you implying that a regular and non-upload form continues to work fine even when logged-in? Nonetheless, in order to help us to better help you, you should at least include sufficient information in the question in such way so that we can reproduce exactly your problem when starting with a scratchpad project using bare defaults and most recent versions. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: non-upload form work fine when logged-in, my problem is form with upload. i try to change using <p:fileUpload> but it doesn't help.

Comment: Well, then you'd need to tell what exactly you're doing on a logged-in request. It is clear that the upload at its own works perfectly fine, but that some login-related checks are corrupting the multipart/form-data request. Perhaps you're examing a request parameter in some servlet filter for some reason? Still, posting a MCVE will increase chance in getting answers or duplicates sooner.

Comment: When making MCVE, I found something weird. So i making new project just like my project for testing but this time i remove unnecessary 3rd party library and then i notice that rewrite servlet is the problem. I'm using this servlet for making pretty url, but i don't understand why this library become a problem? So right now rewrite servlet is remove from my library and everything works fine. Thanks BalusC for your help :)